# Get Random values from mySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have a table with columns `subjects,questions,exam,question id`, from this table I want to get random values to display.

For every every question I have used:

```
$singleSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='$question' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
```

For every subject:

```
$singleSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='$question' AND subject='ayooooo' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
```

I want to display random questions when ever page loads and hen next question is asked.

```
quiz.php?question='
```

How should I use it here?

JavaScript:

```
function getQuestion() {
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var response = hr.responseText.split("|");
            if (response[0] == "finished") {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response[1];
            }
            var nums = hr.responseText.split(",");
            document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = nums[0];
            document.getElementById('answers').innerHTML = nums[1];
            document.getElementById('answers').innerHTML += nums[2];
        }
    }
    hr.open("GET", "questions.php?question=" + <? php echo $question; ?> , true);
    hr.send();
}

function x() {
    var rads = document.getElementsByName("rads");
    for (var i = 0; i < rads.length; i++) {
        if (rads[i].checked) {
            var val = rads[i].value;
            return val;
        }
    }
}

function post_answer() {
    var p = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var id = document.getElementById('qid').value;
    var url = "userAnswers.php";
    var vars = "qid=" + id + "&radio=" + x();
    p.open("POST", url, true);
    p.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-  urlencoded");
    p.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (p.readyState == 4 && p.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = '';
            var url = 'quiz.php?question=<?php echo $next; ?>';
            window.location = url;
        }
    }

    p.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("status")
```

Comment: That is no jquery code!

Comment: PHP is inbetween there. If you're having trouble getting someting from MySQL, look at MySQL alone, or maybe MySQL and PHP together. Javascript has nothing to do with it, and you would make debugging a lot easier for yourself if you narrowed your problem down.

Comment: If I am getting the problem correct, you just need to get a random question when a user hits `quiz.php`, you can just omit parts of your SQL query to do that - `SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1` should work.